# How to avoid deployment of apps and adapters twice on Mobilefirst?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

We have developed multiple apps and adapters as part of our project

We have written little ant scripts to deploy the 'apps' and 'adapters',

Prior executing 'ant tasks' we want to know whether the apps and adapters were already deployed or not

Can I use the tables 'PROJECT_ADAPTERS' and 'PROJECT_APPLICATIONS' to avoid the duplicate deployment?  (or)  What will happen if try to deploy same 'apps' and 'adapters' twice by mistake ?

Comment: Please provide the ant script you are suing to deploy

Answer (score 0):

You should treat the worklight server as a black-box, although in purely technical terms you can investigate the database and deduce information in doing so you are not using a formal API and hence anything you do is unsupported and may become invalid in future product releases.

However there are published ant tasks for retrieving the list of deployed applications and adapters, so in principle you can use those. However I query the wisdom of doing so. My primary concern is that I don't see how knowing that some version of your artefact is deployed is significant. Suppose you have changed the source, don't you want to deploy anyway?

The ant tasks are documented in the InfoCentre. Search for the topic Administering MobileFirst Applications through ant. Here's a [link that works](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.appadmin.doc/admin/r_wladm_ant_app_commands.html) today.

As Idan has indicated there is some degree of cleverness in the build tools to avoid redundant deployment. I suggest you just use the tools as they stand rather than try to circumvent them via back-door approaches.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  If possible, can you point out me the URL to refer the 'ant tasks' which is used to retrieve the list of deployed apps and adapters

Answer (score -1):

Nothing bad will happen by re-deploying an adapter or application.

In fact, if the checksum is identical between the already-deployed .wlapp/.adapter and the to-be deployed .wlapp/.adapter, it may not get deployed at all. And if they do get deployed, twice, and it's exactly the same apps and adapters (no code changes), then they'll just be deployed again (they will *not* be duplicated).

Comment: The table 'PROJECT_ADAPTERS' and 'PROJECT_APPLICATIONS' are part of database 'WLADMIN'.  There are some entries in there  respectively when we deploy apps and adapters.  However, thanks for your reply